# Banco de dados compartilhado

Tags: banco-de-dados

Primeiramente não tenho experiência com bancos de dados. Bem, minha dúvida é a seguinte, como criar um banco de dados para uma aplicação android, em que dados cadastrados nela, pudessem ser acessados por todos aqueles que possuam o app instalado? Tenho que encontrar um servidor para hospedar este banco certo?

Comment: Você precisa de um BD que possa ser acessado online, daí você sincroniza o BD local do dispositivo do usuários com o BD online sempre que possível.

Comment: Você teria que procurar um Serviço de hospedagem de banco de dados e Gerenciamento, a "www.rackspace.com" oferece esse tipo de serviço, entre outras empresas de hospedagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usar um banco de dados diretamente através da Internet é possível, mas muito arriscado em termos de segurança e confiabilidade. Acredito que bancos tradicionais tipo MySQL presumem uma conexão estável entre cliente e servidor.

Você precisa de uma arquitetura "three-tier", ou três camadas, onde o celular conecta com um servidor de aplicação, que por sua vez conversa com o banco de dados (que pode rodar na mesma máquina do servidor).

O estado da tecnologia atual encoraja a usar a seguinte solução: um servidor HTTP, que pode ser escrito em PHP ou em Node.js; um protocolo JSON entre cliente e servidor (você teria de desenhar esse protocolo, mas não faltam exemplos para imitar, talvez valha a pena verificar as padronagens REST e CRUD que talvez se apliquem a seu caso).

O uso de JSON como base do protocolo, e HTTP como serviço de rede, facilita as coisas porque você vai encontrar as ferramentas facilmente. Toda linguagem tem um parser JSON e facilidades para comunicar-se via HTTP. A outra vantagem é que cada requisição HTTP é uma conexão TCP/IP separada, o que ajuda muito com a questão da confiabilidade (a Internet só precisa ficar ativa no momento da requisição, e não durante toooodo o tempo que o usuário estiver usando seu app, como seria o caso se seu app conectasse diretamente com um servidor MySQL remoto)

Por último, talvez existem bancos de dados com interface direta HTTP, estilo REST ou CRUD, o que pouparia você de desenvolver o servidor HTTP de aplicação. Também encontrei este produto; http://www.slashdb.com/ que faz basicamente isso (adapta qualquer banco a uma API HTTP). Eu preferiria criar um servidor de aplicação intermediário para que meu app não ficasse muito amarrado a um banco de dados em particular, mas cada projeto tem suas prioridades.